# How to limit which characters are permitted in strings?

Tags: c#, string

I'm currently making a user class in c# that contains a first name, last name, username and email.

The username can only contain numbers [0-9], lower-case letters [a-z] and underscores '_'

The email can only contain [a-z], [A-Z], [0-9], as well as dot '.', comma ',', underscore '_' and hyphen '-'

How are these limitations set to strings in c#?

Comment: look up regex...

Comment: What framework are you using? if you are using MVC or MVV then you can use Data annotations.

Comment: Catch these at the source of input. Prevent the garbage from coming in.

Comment: there are so many examples online on how to do this, not to mention several different ways that you can approach this for example `RegEx` or you could use the `char.IsNumeric` function please do a little bit more research on your end.. also look up the .`Contains` method

Comment: We're only permitted to use a c# console application for this.

Comment: Side note: your idea what email addresses can contain is over-restrictive and would block some perfectly valid email addresses, e.g. "foo+bar@gmail.com" or "夏明@域通联达。在线" (yep, IDNs may be a lot of headache, but they're perfectly valid). A general suggestion is to only check that there is a "@" character in the address (which is, indeed, a mandatory part), and that you can actually reach the user by sending to that address (i.e. no SMTP errors and user can read your email and visit a link back).

Comment: It's a program we've been tasked to make, so I don't decide which characters are legal, and which ones are not. Unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this logic in the setters of the properties.
ex:

```
private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this._firstName; }
        set
        {
            if (Regex.Match(value, YOUR_REGEX).Success)
                this._firstName = value;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the goal of this project is to get you to know how to use *Regular Expressions*. A good online resource for this which contains common patterns and testing is located at the [Regular Expression Library](http://www.regexlib.com/)

The simple email validation requirement you have can also be done with RegEx, but is actually incorrect as it will allow invalid addresses through; commas can be in an email address but they would need to be quoted which your pattern does not allow.  The specifications for the *local* portion of an email address is probably one of the most poorly implemented standards on the internet.

For future reference, a cheat for checking email addresses within .Net is to use the `MailAddress` class of the `System.Net.Mail` namespace. You can use a `try...catch` routine to see if the submitted address can be converted. The only problems to be aware of using this is it will allow addresses through which most people would not consider to be valid even though they are; such as a server name without an extension (.com etc).

```
private bool isValidEmail (string emailAddress) {
    bool ReturnValue;

    try {
        MailAddress ma = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
        ReturnValue = true;
    }
    catch (Exception) { ReturnValue = false; }

    return ReturnValue;
}
```